# Why QLocalSocket is designed to be connected only to local pipes in "Windows"?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, named-pipes, qlocalsocket

So in QT5.7.0 sources *qlocalsocket_win.cpp* there are lines:

```
const QLatin1String pipePath("\\\\.\\pipe\\");
if (d->serverName.startsWith(pipePath))
    d->fullServerName = d->serverName;
else
    d->fullServerName = pipePath + d->serverName;
```

So there aren't a chance to connect to a pipe on another PC. I've changed few lines, recompile Qt5Network.dll and all worked fine. Is there any reasons to bound QLocalSocket only to local pipes?

Comment: That is not local, is it?

Comment: Socket is local, but server should be possible to be remote.